# Android setSelection(index) ListView with HeaderView sets 1 less index

Tags: android, android-listview

There is ListView with **HeaderView**, when I am setting index with setSelection API it will set wrong(1 less) index as selected index.

Following is code snippest :

```
final ListView lst = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
LinearLayout headerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
headerLayout.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
headerLayout.setId(9);
lst.addHeaderView(headerLayout, null, false);'code'
```

e.g.

```
listView.setSelection(6);
```

---

```
Button btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                lst.setSelection(6);
                View v1 = lst.getChildAt(0);
                int top = (v1 == null) ? 0 : v1.getTop();
                lst.setSelectionFromTop(6, top);    

                //lst.setSelection(6);

            }});
```

This will set focus to **5th position** item as selected item.

I have tried with

```
View v1 = listView.getChildAt(0);
View n = lst.findViewById(9); // 9 is id of listView's header.
listView.setSelectionFromTop(6, n.getMeasuredHeight());
```

and

```
View v1 = listView.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v1 == null) ? 0 : v1.getTop();
listView.setSelectionFromTop(6, top);
```

But this also won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`int index = 6(this can be any number or value) + 1`

```
listView.setSelection(index);
View v1 = listView.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v1 == null) ? 0 : v1.getTop();
listView.setSelectionFromTop(index, n.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Comment: I do not want to hardcode '+1', is there any alternative for this?

Comment: may be the header is also added as an item that is why you must be getting like that, try removing the header and see

Comment: I want to achieve this with HeaderView only